# Parameter name is missing in HTTP Request in jmeter?

Tags: file-upload, jmeter

In Jmeter HTTP request, send files with the request option is there.Here name attribute is not displayed.So I unable to enter the parameter name.how to upload the file or image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [section HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) in Apache JMeter, as you can see in below screenshot,

1. You could use Browse... for file upload option.
2. You could enter parametername as well.

Hope it helps.

[image: JMeter Apache HTTP Request]

Comment: Thanks.How to know the Parameter name?

Comment: 1. You could accept this answer if it has helped you :) 2. Depending on your requirement, you could set ParameterName.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can record file upload (just make sure that file(s) you're uploading live in JMeter's "bin" folder). JMeter is smart enough to detect "Parameter Name" and MIME type
2. If you don't want or cannot record - look into the page source and search for [input type="file ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535263(v=vs.85).aspx) line.

   `name` attribute will be "Parameter Name" you're looking for. I.e. for StackOverflow upload dialog it will be `file`

   [image: Stackoverflow upload]

See [How to Test Image Upload Functionality With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-test-image-upload-functionality-jmeter) guide for a little bit more detailed information on simulating file upload in your Jmeter test.

Comment: Suppose name attribute is missing.How to give the parameter name?